# Resolution for reopened task in Jira

Tags: workflow, jira, issue-tracking

What resolution is more correct in case:
an issue was resolve and resolution was fixed, but QA added bug in comment and reopen the issue, Developer answered that bug from comment will fixed in another task and return status to "resolved". So, what resolution more suitable for this issue now? Duplicated/Won't fix or it must remain the same (I mean Resolve)?

Answer (score 2):

This is less of a functional question because it relates more to how your company operates.

My take on this is that the Defect should be returned to Closed-Resolved because the defect was addressed in the sprint by Dev and QA.

However, when the issue appeared again, it most likely didn't appear due to the reasons that the defect appeared the first time, so it is fundamentally a new issue.

The first defect would be returned to Closed-Resolved with the associated Work Logged against it and any new Work or Time spent against this new issue would be recorded against the new defect along with its associated Resolution (i.e. if you decide to close it as "Will Not Fix")

In the end, I believe that it is entirely up to you!